# Supervisor alternatives on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting, supervisord

I have deployed my app on shared host "Hostgator", I've ssh successfull access, however I can't install supervisor to manage queue processing, the command `sudo apt-get install supervisor` always return errors, so I have contacted support and I was told that I can't make `sudo` commands with sharedhost "cloud" plan and I have to move to VPS or dedicated which I can't move to at this time.

My question is : is there any alternative can I use to manage the queue processing without supervisor or another way to go around this ? anybody wen through this and found a solution ?

I was thinking to make a cron job with command `php artisan queue:work` every morning maybe but is this a good practice ?

Thanks in advance any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone there who is going through something similar, I managed that by cron jobs that run every hour but you have to migrate failed jobs table to make sure that failed jobs are handled and don't stop the queue processing, even though this is not ideal but it somehow works. The ideal solution is considering VPS hosting or mixing Laravel Forge with DigitalOcean for example as mentioned in laravel docs.

Cheers.

Comment: I planned to use cron jobs because using supervisord on host it is very pain except some host like forge...